# How to transform an array with objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I need to transfrm an array into another array but can't find a good way to do this. An error message tells me I can't push into `found[0].children`, but I feel like all the way I'm doing it wrong and dirty; would you tell me how you manage this kind of issue?

I would like to transform the array:

```
const input =
[
    {value: "29-08-2020 16:00", visible: 0},
    {value: "29-08-2020 16:30", visible: 1},
    {value: "29-08-2020 17:00", visible: 0},
    {value: "30-08-2020 15:00", visible: 1},
    {value: "30-08-2020 15:30", visible: 1}
];
```

Into the array:

```
const output =
[
    {
        id: '29/08/2020',
        label: '29/08/2020',
        children:
        [
            {
                id: '16:00',
                label: '16:00',
                isDisabled: true
            },
            {
                id: '16:30',
                label: '16:30'
            },
            {
                id: '17:00',
                label: '17:00',
                isDisabled: true
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        id: '30/08/2020',
        label: '30/08/2020',
        children:
        [
            {
                id: '15:00',
                label: '15:00'
            },
            {
                id: '15:30',
                label: '15:30'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Here is what I tried, but I am not satisfied at all with this idea, which doesn't seem like the good way...

```
function dateoptions(dateslist) {
    var options: any[] = [];
    dateslist.forEach(element => {
        var tab = element.value.split(' ');
        var dt = tab[0];
        var time = tab[1];
        var found = options.filter(opt=> opt.id==dt);
        if (found.length>0) {
            // I can't do this:
            found[0].children.push({
                'id': time,
                'label': time,
                disabled: element.visible==0
            });
        }
        else {
            options.push({
                'id': dt,
                'label': dt,
                'children': {'id':time, 'label': time, disabled: element.visible==0}
            });
        }
    });
    return options;
}
```

Comment: can you precise the `options` structure to be sure please ?
note : you are using forEach method but you keep returns options. it does nothing

Comment: The return is outside of the forEach

Comment: @gertrude, see my solution. Maybe you would like also to mark my answer as accepted because it is supported in all brousers.

Comment: indeed, thanks for your answer! We won't use IE but it's a good alternative :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general idea is good, I'd use a map<sup>1</sup> for simplicity of the lookup and create an empty entry (with empty children array) when not found:

```js
function dateoptions (datelist) {
  const dateObjects = new Map()

  for (const { value, visible } of datelist) {
    const [date, time] = value.split(' ')

    if (!dateObjects.has(date)) {
      dateObjects.set(date, {
        id: date,
        label: date,
        children: []
      })
    }

    dateObjects.get(date).children.push({
      id: time,
      label: time,
      ...!visible ? { isDisabled: true } : {}
    })
  }

  return Array.from(dateObjects.values())
}
```

---

<sub>**1:** Why not an object? Because the iteration order of object values is not defined, even though practically all current browsers use insertion order. For a map it is defined.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You could reduce the array and iterate the result set for a same group.

```js
const
    data = [{ value: "29-08-2020 16:00", visible: 0 }, { value: "29-08-2020 16:30", visible: 1 }, { value: "29-08-2020 17:00", visible: 0 }, { value: "30-08-2020 15:00", visible: 1 }, { value: "30-08-2020 15:30", visible: 1 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { value, visible }) => {
        let [date, time] = value.split(' '),
            temp = r.find(q => q.id === date);
       
        if (!temp) r.push(temp = { id: date, label: date, children: [] });
        temp.children.push({ id: time, label: time, ...(!visible && { isDisabled: !visible }) });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solution is supported even in Internet Explorer 6.

```js
var input =
[
    {value: "29-08-2020 16:00", visible: 0},
    {value: "29-08-2020 16:30", visible: 1},
    {value: "29-08-2020 17:00", visible: 0},
    {value: "30-08-2020 15:00", visible: 1},
    {value: "30-08-2020 15:30", visible: 1}
];

function dateTransform(datelist)
{
    var ret = [],
        dateObjects = {},
        i;

    for(i in datelist)
    {
        var obj = datelist[i],
            ar = obj.value.split(' '),
            date = ar[0].split('-').join('/'),
            child = {id: ar[1], label: ar[1]};

        if(!dateObjects[date])
            dateObjects[date] = {id: date, label: date, children: []};

        if(!obj.visible)
            child.isDisabled = !0;

        dateObjects[date].children.push(child)
    }

    for(i in dateObjects)
        ret.push(dateObjects[i]);

    return ret
}

//JSON.stringify is supported first in Internet Explorer 8 version
console.log(JSON.stringify(dateTransform(input), 0, '\t'));
```